# Define CSS Transition effect (Start and End Positioning)

Tags: css, css-transitions

A small CSS transition effect:

```css
div#Back a {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 6%;
    color: #cccccc;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 5%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-variant: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

div#Back a:hover {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
    
    -webkit-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="Back"><a onclick="goBack();">Back</a></div>
```

The hover effect works fine, but the transition to the original does not work. It jumps directly. What is the problem?

Comment: Please add the js code for goBack, There is an error while I'm trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specified `transition` for the hover state only - so there is no transition when the state change in the other “direction”, from hover back to normal, happens.

Specify `transition` for both. (Since the :hover state “inherits” the values from the normal state, it is enough to specify it for the normal state only here.)

```css
div#Back a {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 6%;
    color: #cccccc;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 5%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-variant: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
}

div#Back a:hover {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="Back"><a onclick="goBack();">Back</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of how the CSS works. You have two selectors there, each with their own rules.

```
div#Back a {
   // rules 1
}

div#Back a:hover {
   // rules 2
}
```

If you hover the `<a>` element, it will execute the `rules 2` set. This set applies a transition effect, hence you see a moving animation to a more rounded button when hovering it.

But when leaving the `<a>` element with the mouse, the hover effect is not active anymore, thus going back to the `rules 1` set. However, it does not contain a transition animation. So the rendering engine will "pop" the style to what is described in the rules. If you want to animate back to the original state, simply define transition rules for that selector and only change the values (for the animation) effect when hovering the element.

```css
div#Back a {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 6%;
    color: #cccccc;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 5%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-variant: inherit;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    
    -webkit-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
    transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
}

div#Back a:hover {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Back"><a onclick="goBack();">Back</a></div>
```

Comment: You don't need the transition on the :hover-state, if the transitions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Put the transition with div#Back instead of the hover.

```css
div#Back a {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 6%;
  color: #cccccc;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 5%;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-variant: inherit;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
  transition: border-radius 2s ease-out;
}

div#Back a:hover {
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Back"><a onclick="goBack();">Back</a></div>
```